# Coldfusion XML Character encoding part 2

Tags: xml, coldfusion, character-encoding

I have a UTF-8 xml file littered with codes like `&#xc3;&#x192;&#xC2;&xA7;` for a cedilla etc
I have written the snippet below to remove or replace with acceptable values
1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. When I run this on some large XML files (>50MB) I may get Out of memory errors. If there is no better way how can I optimize it avoid OOM errors?

```
<cffile 
    action="read"
    file="#ExpandPath('./xs.xml')#"
    variable="myfile"/>

<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,'&##xC2;&##x2013;','.','all')/>
<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,'&##xC2;&##x2019;','''','all')/>
<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,'&##xC2;&##x201D;','"','all')/>

<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,'&##xC3;&##x192;&##xC2;&##xA7;','c','all')/>
<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,'&##xC3;&##xA7;','c','all')/>
<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,'&##xC3;&##xA9;','e','all')/>
<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,'&##xC3;&##x201A;&##xC2;&##x2022;','(*)','all')/>
<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,'&##xC3;&##x192;&##xC2;&##x201A;\?','(*)','all')/>
<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,'&##xC3;&##x201A;&##xC2;&##xB7;','-','all')/>
<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,'&##xC3;&##x201A;&##xC2;&##x2018;','''','all')/>
<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,' &##xC3;&##x201A;&##xC2;&##x201C;',' "','all')/>

<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,'&##xE2;&##x20AC;&##x201C;','-','all')/>
<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,'&##xE2;&##x20AC;&##x2122;','''','all')/>
<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,' &##xE2;&##x20AC;&##x153;',' "','all')/>
<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,'&##xE2;&##x20AC;&##x153;','-','all')/>
<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,'&##xE2;&##x20AC;&##xFFFD; ','" ','all')/>
<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,'&##xE2;&##x20AC;&##xFFFD;','-','all')/>
<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,'&##xE2;&##x201E;&##xA2;','(TM)','all')/>
<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,'&##xE2;&##x20AC;&##xA2;','(*)','all')/>

<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,'&##xEF;&##x201A;&##xA7;','(*)','all')/>

<cfset myfile =ReReplace(myfile,'(&##[^;]*;)','','all')/>

<cffile action="write"
     file="#ExpandPath('./xs_new.xml')#"
     output="#myfile#"/>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ColdFusion's file functions to work on one line at a time, instead of reading the entire thing into memory:

```
<cfscript>
myfile = FileOpen(ExpandPath('./xs.xml'), "read"); 
myNewFile = FileOpen(ExpandPath('./xs_new.xml'), "write"); 

while(NOT FileisEOF(myfile)) { 
    line = FileReadLine(myfile); // read line 

    line = ReReplace(line,'&##xC2;&##x2013;','.','all');
    line = ReReplace(line,'&##xC2;&##x2019;','''','all');
    line = ReReplace(line,'&##xC2;&##x201D;','"','all');

    line = ReReplace(line,'&##xC3;&##x192;&##xC2;&##xA7;','c','all');
    line = ReReplace(line,'&##xC3;&##xA7;','c','all');
    line = ReReplace(line,'&##xC3;&##xA9;','e','all');
    line = ReReplace(line,'&##xC3;&##x201A;&##xC2;&##x2022;','(*)','all');
    line = ReReplace(line,'&##xC3;&##x192;&##xC2;&##x201A;\?','(*)','all');
    line = ReReplace(line,'&##xC3;&##x201A;&##xC2;&##xB7;','-','all');
    line = ReReplace(line,'&##xC3;&##x201A;&##xC2;&##x2018;','''','all');
    line = ReReplace(line,' &##xC3;&##x201A;&##xC2;&##x201C;',' "','all');

    line = ReReplace(line,'&##xE2;&##x20AC;&##x201C;','-','all');
    line = ReReplace(line,'&##xE2;&##x20AC;&##x2122;','''','all');
    line = ReReplace(line,' &##xE2;&##x20AC;&##x153;',' "','all');
    line = ReReplace(line,'&##xE2;&##x20AC;&##x153;','-','all');
    line = ReReplace(line,'&##xE2;&##x20AC;&##xFFFD; ','" ','all');
    line = ReReplace(line,'&##xE2;&##x20AC;&##xFFFD;','-','all');
    line = ReReplace(line,'&##xE2;&##x201E;&##xA2;','(TM)','all');
    line = ReReplace(line,'&##xE2;&##x20AC;&##xA2;','(*)','all');

    line = ReReplace(line,'&##xEF;&##x201A;&##xA7;','(*)','all');

    line = ReReplace(line,'(&##[^;]*;)','','all');  

    fileWrite(line);
} 

FileClose(myfile); 
FileClose(myNewFile);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: or use <cfloop index="line" file="#filePath#"> if you prefer CFML instead of CFScript - http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2011-Reading-In-File-Data-One-Line-At-A-Time-Using-ColdFusion-s-CFLoop-Tag-Or-Java-s-LineNumberReader.htm